# Mysql string input with formatting

Tags: php, mysql, command-line, formatting, phpmyadmin

I am a beginner at MySQL and I am having a little trouble with the correct formatting for a cell in my table.

I have the data type set to `TEXT` so there is plenty of space for a few small paragraphs within the cell however my problem is, how do I format the paragraph with apostrophes, quotes, colons, and other punctuation that I am inserting into that cell via command line (MAC)?

This is what the column values are:

```
joke TEXT NOT NULL,
```

I want to insert this example joke into the table:

```
Husband says: "When I'm gone you'll never find another man like me".
Wife replied: "What makes you think I'd want another man like you!"
```

How do I write it into command line so it will display the exact formatting or at least something close. My command line entry looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO jokes
(date_submitted, source, joke_style, joke)
VALUES
(NOW(), 'www.example.com','Blonde', 'Joke would go here with (: ' ,) and so on.');
```

Do I escape the apostrophes with `\'`? What do I do with the rest of the punctuation, and how do I store line breaks?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or switch to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and use [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) with placeholders.

Example:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO jokes ... VALUES (NOW, :joke, ...)');
$sth->execute(array(':joke' => $joke));
```

If you need to write commands manually, you should escape `'` as `\'`, and the newline character is `\n`. For more details about how strings are escaped in MySQL, see the manual section about [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

Comment: +1 for PDO - switch over your learning curve and spend the time on that.  PDO lets you use the same SQL, with (almost?) all flavors of database products.  It will cost you about the same sweat and tears as learning PHP/MySQL interaction, but with a big payoff in the long run.

Comment: Can I implement this within mysql command line? I am entering data manually and I have not yet created a script to write user data to the table.

Comment: @DerekGutierrez, this is what you would do with PHP (since I saw the PHP tag in your question). If you want to escape strings in MySQL commands, take a look at the MySQL manual section about [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) for a complete description of how strings are escaped.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Your example will help when I incorporate a php script into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

heres an excerpt from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

The following SELECT statements demonstrate how quoting and escaping work:

```
mysql> SELECT 'hello', '"hello"', '""hello""', 'hel''lo', '\'hello';
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
| hello | "hello" | ""hello"" | hel'lo | 'hello |
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+

mysql> SELECT "hello", "'hello'", "''hello''", "hel""lo", "\"hello";
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
| hello | 'hello' | ''hello'' | hel"lo | "hello |
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+

mysql> SELECT 'This\nIs\nFour\nLines';
+--------------------+
| This
Is
Four
Lines |
+--------------------+

mysql> SELECT 'disappearing\ backslash';
+------------------------+
| disappearing backslash |
+------------------------+
```